# PostgreSQL execute SELECT * FROM (t as a); return ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"

Tags: postgresql

Why these SQLs can't work in PostgreSQL?

```
SELECT * FROM (t as a);
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM (t);
```

`ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"`

Those SQLs work well in MySQL.

Comment: MySQL is not a reference when it comes to "valid" SQL syntax. It also accepts things like `WHERE 'bla'`. If in doubt, Postgres is probably right and MySQL isn't

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's invalid SQL.

If you want to give the table an alias you need to use `from t as a`.

The form `from (....)` requires a valid query inside the parentheses and `t as a` (or just `t`) is not a valid query. Additionally: a derived table (which is what `(...)` defines) requires an alias. So at least it has to be `from (...) as bla`

To get all rows and all columns from a table the SQL standard provides the shortcut `table some_table` which is supported by Postgres.

So the following would be valid:

```
select * from (table t) as a
```

Comment: Tidb-parser parse the SQL like `SELECT * from t1, t2, t3;`  => `SELECT * FROM ((t1) JOIN t2) JOIN t3`. This may add brackets for priority, which can't pass postgreSQL syntax check.

Comment: No idea what "tidb" is, but `t1, t2, t3` is the same as `t1 cross join t2 cross join t3` . A `JOIN` needs an `ON` condition.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, table alias' are applied where there is a join. For example:

```
SELECT alias1.login_name, alias2.name 
FROM tablename1 AS alias1
JOIN tablename2 AS alias2
ON alias1.id = alias2.role_id;
```

To apply an alias to a single table:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename AS alias;
```

..will do it for you, no need for parentheses.

You can confirm/test by example below if *value* is an **integer**:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename AS alias 
WHERE alias.colum = value;
```

..or if *value* is a **string**:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename AS alias 
WHERE alias.colum = 'value';
```

postgreSQL is strongly-typed, so the first example above will work for Int and Bool values, however if you have Date or other values, you may need to apply type casting. See this link for helpful info*: [www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-cast](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-cast).

****Remember:** For psql strings, always use **single quotes** for **values**, use *double quotes* for table *names* and column *names*.